# "Submatrix incorrectly defined" when trying to decrease color depth of greyscale images

Tags: image, matrix, scilab, submatrix

I'm trying to make Scilab receive a certain JPEG image then transform it into a matrix of values between 0 and 255 (normal 8bit depth image) and then rearrange those values into smaller depths. The proposal is to make all the options from 1bit to 7bits which translates into 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 and 128 different levels of color for them respectively.

We're doing it with greyscale images to make things simpler, since we can simply get any of the 3 channels and work with it as a matrix of rows and columns. I know there are many better ways of doing this, but I need to do it using Scilab since it's for a image processing course at University (signals and linear systems subject from Electrical Engineering to be exact).

What I could come up with, and it worked fine for the test-matrices that I tried, is this:

```
function y=bits(x,p)
    [rows, columns]=size(x);
    y=zeros(rows,columns);
    aux=round(linspace(0,255,2^p));  //define which values the output can have  
   for i=1:rows                     //varies rows
        for j=1:columns               //varies columns
        [aux2,minpos]=min(abs(aux-x(i,j)));//calculates the closest value between the input and the possible output values
        y(i,j)=aux(minpos); //get the calculated closest value and puts it at the output
    end
  end  
endfunction
```

What I can't understand is why it works fine for any hand-made matrix but when I try to send it something bigger (I mean, which more rows and columns) it gives the "Submatrix incorrectly defined." error at line 8 which is the " y(i,j)=aux(minpos);" line.

Edit: Just to add, I'm importing the image using "imread", which is a function of SIVP.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it with the following at the beginning of the function:

```
x=x(:,:,1);
x=double(x);
```

=).

Comment: If you accept your own answer you can show your problem is solved (and collect some points in the process)